# Google Cloud Storage fonts import issue

Tags: html, css, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, bucket

I'm getting some problems while importing a font located in Google Cloud Services in an specific storage bucket. I placed the next block of code inside  in a html file.

```
@font-face {
     font-family: 'font-name';
     src:url('[font-public-link-inside-gcs-bucket]') format('truetype')
}
```

After this import, font-family: 'font-name' is not working.

Comment: Does the Chrome debugger indicate a problem downloading the font src URL?